# How to clear form in volt view after submit?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

This is the view before submit :

[image]

After i fill the form and submit it, the entry records still there when i using volt.

[image]

how can i clear it ?
This is my Form :

```
class BataorderForm extends \Phalcon\Forms\Form{
    public function initialize(){

        $protComsId   = new Select('protComsId',CompanyMaster::find(),[
            'class'         => 'btn btn-default btn-block',
            'using'         => ['comsId','comsName'],
            'useEmpty'      => true,
            'emptyText'     => '-- Choose Company --',
            'emptyValue'    => ''
        ]);
        $protComsId->setLabel('Company Master');
        $this->add($protComsId);
}
```

Comment: Also i think you don't need all columns from CompanyMaster ? I guess it will not be a problem if there will be only 2 columns but if more then it's not necessary to select only for form :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset every element in a form you have to call the method `clear()`

**Example controller usage:**

```
$form = new YourForm();
if ($this->request->isPost() AND $this->security->checkToken() AND $form->isValid($this->request->getPost())) {
    // Form is valid
} else {
    // Form is not valid. Let's reset it to annoy our user :)
    $form->clear();
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

More info on form methods in the [Documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Forms_Form.html).

Comment: you save my day again .. i love you Niki

Comment: do you use phalcon and microservice ?

Comment: Do you mean Phalcon [Micro applications](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html) ? If yes, no I have not used them yet, most of my applications use Multi module structure.

Comment: thanks for your appreciate..  im really glad..
do u use decoupled system? such as backend and frontend..?

i mean software architecture : microservice.. do u use rest phalcon?
thanks again Niki !